# WCF Service not Starting Using Browse in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I have published a WCF service in IIS however when I run the code (browse the site from within Iis) I just get the following line displayed in the browser.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service=......."
```

Any ideas why this is showing?

Comment: Member for two years and you post the above question?  What do you mean by "when I run the code" - what code?  What are the steps to reproduce?

Comment: I go to my site in iis. Click browse.... It opens up an ie window and then just shows one line of code on a white background (the one above).

Comment: Also updated above to be more clear....

Comment: Might be a mapping in IIS.   Try running the [ServiceModel Registration Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because the WCF features were not all enabled on the server.